# PreparedStatement - как правильно использовать?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, preparedstatement

```
package sqlite;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programm{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Programm bd = new Programm();
        bd.open();
        bd.create();
        bd.insert();
        bd.close();

    }

    Connection co;

    void open() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:track.db");
            System.out.println("Connected");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
    void create() {
        try {
        Statement statement = co.createStatement();
        String query = 
                "CREATE TABLE if not exists 'track_data' ( "+
                        "TIME_IN_MS DOUBLE PRECISION, " +
                        "EKG1 DOUBLE PRECISION); ";
        statement.execute(query);
        System.out.println("Таблица создана или уже существует.");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
    void insert() {
        try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double time = 2;
        double ekg_1 = 3;
        String query = "INSERT INTO tracks (TIME_IN_MS, EKG1) " +
                "VALUES ('" + time +"','"+ ekg_1+"')";
        Statement statement = co.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(query);
        System.out.println("Rows added");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    void close() {
        try {
            co.close();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь изменить statement на `PreparedStatement`, не получается

```
package sqlite;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Programm{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Programm bd = new Programm();
        bd.open();
        //bd.create();
        bd.insert();
        bd.close();

    }

    Connection co;
    PreparedStatement prepstatement;

    void open() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            co = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:track_test.db");
            System.out.println("Connected");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
    /*void create() {
        try {
            statement = co.createStatement();
        String query = 
                "CREATE TABLE if not exists 'track_data' ( "+
                        "TIME_IN_MS DOUBLE PRECISION, " +
                        "EKG1 DOUBLE PRECISION); ";
        statement.execute(query);
        System.out.println("Таблица создана или уже существует.");

        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }*/

    void insert() {
        try {
            prepstatement = co.prepareStatement(
                       "UPDATE track_data SET EKG1 = ? WHERE TIME_IN_MS = ?");
            double time = 2;
            double ekg_1 = 3;

            prepstatement.setDouble();
            System.out.println("Rows added");


        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    void close() {
        try {
            co.close();
            System.out.println("Таблица закрыта");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно использовать `PreparedStatement` ? И как с его помощью создать таблицу ?

Comment: В чем вы пишите код? Как IDE Вам пропустила вызов prepstatement.setDouble() без параметров?

Comment: @Maxim здесь специально оставлено это без параметров, так как я не понимаю, какой параметр куда должен записываться(надо было это обозначить, прошу прощения). Вставляю разные параметры, чтобы понять,вроде бы выдаёт "Rows added", но, по факту, ничего не записалось, в чём дело не знаю

Comment: Первый параметр это номер вопросительного знака из запроса, начиная с 1, второй параметр - значение которое нужно туда подставить, более подробно есть в javadoc к этому методу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создать таблицу вам не нужно `PreparedStatement`. А для того чтобы подставить значения в SQL можно использовать следующий код

```
String query = "INSERT INTO tracks (TIME_IN_MS, EKG1) " +
        "VALUES (?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement = co.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setDouble(1, time);
statement.setDouble(2, ekg_1); 
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы не подскажите ещё пожалуйста способы оптимизации запросов ?

Comment: Вы можете использовать `PreparedStatement`  несколько раз.

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее было бы так:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO tracks (TIME_IN_MS, EKG1) VALUES (?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement statement = co.prepareStatement(query))
{
    statement.setDouble(1, time);
    statement.setDouble(2, ekg_1); 
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Ресурс должен освобождаться после использования.

Comment: Спасибо!! Сможете подсказать пожалуйста ещё способы оптимизации запросов?