# Как впихнуть в SQL запрос переменную?

Tags: java, postgresql, variable

Есть postgres DB, пользователь вводит почту и пароль, по этим данным нужно вывести ему из другой таблицы его счета. Как в запросе в Java закинуть эту переменную, например, почту, в условие where. То есть, к примеру, where u.email = Mail(стринговая переменная, которую вводит пользователь).

Comment: Необходимо уточнить какими средствами происходит взаимодействия с БД

Comment: Для взаимодействия с бд используем JDBC

Comment: `"where u.email = " + Mail`?

Comment: Всегда используйте подготовленный запрос, который может принимать ограниченное количество параметров. [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851340/204920) пример взятый из моего ответа. Есть вариант выполнить один запрос и другой вариант, два запроса. В первом надо написать SQL и связать две таблицы по ключу пользователя, второй сначала получить ключ пользователя и потом использовать его как параметр в другом запросе.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ:

```
String sql = "select * from table where email = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, "email@email.com"); 
ps.executeUpdate();
ps.close();
```

- в `ps.setString(1, "email@email.com");` единица означает порядковый номер подставляемого параметра.

Изучите методы `PreparedStatement`, для каждого типа есть свои методы (`setLong, setDouble, etc...`)

Соответственно сеттеры будут принимать первым параметром номер подставляемого параметра.

[Вот](https://metanit.com/java/database/2.6.php) для изучения других параметризированных SQL запросов через знак вопроса