# Не получается внести данные в базу данных. Java

Tags: java, postgresql, csv, jdbc

```
 String les = (String) ls.get(i);
 String les1 = (String) ls.get(i+1);
 int rs = stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO farms (namefarms, twonamefarms) VALUES ("+les+", "+les1+")");
```

Сразу скажу, что я начинаю только программировать. Я выгружаю данные с csv файла. Не знаю важно ли это, в csv файле данные на русском. Выгружаю их в список list, затем перекидываю по циклу в мою базу данных.

Выгружать их в список получается, но проблема в том, чтобы занести в базу.

Выводит

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "К").

Comment: Если что, то i = 0. Тут я для примера пытался ввести первые два элемента списка в базу. Но выдает уже на них ошибку.

Comment: текстовые данные в запросе должны быть в кавычках

Comment: в запросе то, что я отправляю в базу данных и так в кавычках. Или я не так что-то выделил?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать `PreparedStatement`, как например в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851340/204920) ответе.

```java
String query = "INSERT INTO farms (namefarms, twonamefarms)" + 
        "VALUES (?,?)";
PreparedStatement statement = co.prepareStatement(query);
statement.setString(1, les1);
statement.setString(2, les2); 
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: спасибо, понял. Все помогло

Answer (score 0):

во-первых надо использовать PreparedStatement, ну а почему именно не работает в этом случае надо добавить кавычки '"+les+"', '"+les1+"')"

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло